# Python import works in interpreter, doesn't work in script Numpy/Matplotlib

Tags: python, path, numpy, matplotlib

I'm on OSX Snow Leopard and I run 2.7 in my scripts and the interpreter seems to be running 2.6

Before I was able to import numpy but then I would get an error when trying to import matplotlib so I went looking for a solution and updated my PYTHONPATH variable, but I think I did it incorrectly and have now simply screwed everything up.

This is what I get when I try and import numpy in my script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "./hh_main.py", line 5, in 
>      import numpy
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 137, in 
>      import add_newdocs
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
>      from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>      from type_check import *
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in 
>      import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 5, in 
>      import multiarray
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCapsule_Import
>    Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
>    Expected in: flat namespace
>   in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so

Furthermore this is what I get from sys.path in the interpreter:

> ['', '/Users/joshuaschneier/Documents/python_files', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']

And this is my PYTHONPATH which I guess I updated wrong:

> :/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll generally need to install numpy, matplotlib etc once for every version of python you use, as it will install itself to the specific 'python2.x/site-packages' directory.

Is the above output generated from a 2.6 or 2.7 session? If it's a 2.6 session, then yes, pointing your PYTHONPATH at 2.7 won't work - numpy includes compiled C code (e.g. the multiarray.so file) which will have been built against a specific version of python.

If you don't fancy maintaining two sets of packages, I'd recommend installing numpy, matplotlib etc all for version 2.7, removing that PYTHONPATH setting, and making sure that both scripts and interpreter sessions use version 2.7.

If you want to keep both versions you'll just have to install each packages twice (and you'll probably still wnat to undo your PTYHONPATH change)

Comment: I have found the problem. The interpreter is running 2.7 but when I look in /usr/bin/ there is only 2.5 and 2.6 for my she-bang to find. Any idea where 2.7 might be hiding? Even after I reinstall it still doesn't appear in /usr/bin

Comment: Got it, just changed it to /usr/local/bin I don't really understand why it isn't in /usr/bin but whatever.